# Is there any way to display an image along with some text and a button all together with response message in react-native-gifted-chat?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm working with react-native-gifted-chat and I want to make a UI similar to a picture attached in a link. I want to add this card type feature along with a response message in react-native-gifted-chat but I dont have a clue whether this is possible to execute with gifted chat or not. [Screenshot of my expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKaCt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this requires creating a custom component that you pass into the renderMessage prop of `<GiftedChat />`:

```
<GiftedChat
  messages={...}
  onSend={...}
  user={...}
  ...
  renderMessage={props => (
    <MyCustomMessage
      {...props}
    />
  )}
/>
```

In this case, `MyCustomMessage` would be a component that contains all of the custom layout/logic you want. [Check out the Slack style UI example](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/tree/master/example-slack-message) in the react-native-gifted-chat repository for a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Bro. I'm bit late to respond. But it was kinda big help.